# Using SUM with formula based row's text content, All together with WHERE, JOIN, ORDER

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am writing a small application about stock monitoring for my company. Using mysql and codeigniter 2.1.0.

Two tables: deliveries and stockcards

I appreciate the help about building a query to list **stock name** and **remaining quantity**.

Final output is desired to be: (pls look below tables)

```
<tr>
  <td>Product Name 1</td>
  <td> 2 pcs </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Product Name 2</td>
  <td> 5 pcs </td>
</tr>
```

I guess the tasks are:

join tables with id_stock,  
group by id_stock 
under each group, get 'somehow' sum of quantity where direction = rcvd 
under each group, get 'somehow' sum of quantity where direction = sent 
'somehow' create a new column for each group with rcvd minus sent = remaining_quantity 
order by stokcards.name ASC

I couldn't manage to make the right fiction and more that the right syntax about it. 
Thanks for any help.

Deliveries:

```
+-------------+----------+-----------+----------+
| id_delivery | id_stock | direction | quantity |
+-------------+----------+-----------+----------+
|    A.I.     |    1     |   rcvd    |     15   |
|             |    1     |   sent    |     13   |
|             |    2     |   rcvd    |     50   |
|             |    2     |   sent    |     45   |
+-------------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

Stockcards:

```
+----------+-----------------+
| id_stock |       name      |
+----------+-----------------+
|    1     |  Product Name 1 |
|    2     |  Product Name 2 |
+----------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.id_stock, 
        b.`name` as ProductName,
        COALESCE(f.TotalReceived, 0) as TotalReceived, 
        COALESCE(g.TotalSent, 0) as TotalSent,
        (COALESCE(f.TotalReceived, 0) - COALESCE(g.TotalSent, 0)) as RemainingStock
FROM    deliveries a INNER JOIN stockcards b 
            ON a.id_stock = b.id_Stock
        LEFT JOIN 
            (
                SELECT c.id_stock, SUM(c.quantity) TotalReceived
                FROM deliveries c
                WHERE c.direction = 'rcvd'
                GROUP BY c.id_stock
            ) f ON a.id_stock = f.id_stock
        LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT d.id_stock, SUM(d.quantity) TotalSent
                FROM deliveries d
                WHERE d.direction = 'sent'
                GROUP BY d.id_stock
            ) g ON a.id_stock = g.id_stock
ORDER BY ProductName ASC
```

Comment: Works fine.. Just edited Line 2, adding comma at the end; and line 5 adding "as" before RemainingStock.. Thank you so much.

Comment: @yahyaE oh my mistake. By the way, the query will still work even without the `AS`. Glad i helped you. :)

Answer (score 1):

In the first instance, if this is a fresh system I would consider recording any that you have sent as negative numbers as that would vastly simplify the problem.  There are alternatives, however if you are either going to be receiving or adding stock then simply having positive for receive and negative for dispatch may well do your job.

As an answer to fit your current schema, the following will do as you have requested

```
SELECT 
  s.*,
  SUM(COALESCE(d_in.quantity,0))-SUM(COALESCE(d_out.quantity,0)) AS quantiyInStock

FROM stockcards AS s

LEFT JOIN deliveries AS d_in
  ON d_in.id_stock = s.id_stock
  AND d_in.direction = 'rcvd'

LEFT JOIN deliveries AS d_out
  ON d_out.id_stock = s.id_stock
  AND d_out.direction = 'sent'

GROUP BY s.id_stock
```

For the above to work as efficiently as it can, you should ensure you have the following key

On table 'deliveries' a key consisting of the columns ('id_stock','id_direction')

Comment: Using all positive numbers filtered by a varchar(4) column, make the things easier for me actually. Till now... Not a fresh system unfortunately. Adding a new report which displays all stocks and remaining quantity momentarily. Any idea fictioning the sql?

Comment: Have edited with a solution that'll use your existing database structure to get the number you'd like.  Will also work when there is a stockcard record with no matching rcvd or sent (returning quantity 0) or with negative numbers (more sent than rcvd ... somehow)

Comment: Thank you, probably the right solution but I couldn't make it adopt my project. thanks anyway.

Comment: No worries, the one you accepted went a bit further anyway to provide full received/sent stats which is conceivably quite useful, and I believe their query was more efficient